# Twitter APIs not working on hosting [Works fine on localhost]

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working on an app to show the tweets done in 1 mile radius of given geolocation (Latitude and Longitude). This is my PHP code,

```
<?php
// $lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lat = 26.511740;

// $long = $_GET['long'];
$long = 80.234973;

require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$notweets = 100;

$consumerkey = "XXXX";
$consumersecret = "XXXX";
$accesstoken = "XXXX-XXXX";
$accesstokensecret = "XXXX"; 

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
} 

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey,$consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?geocode=".$lat.",".$long.",5mi&result_type=recent&count=".$notweets);

// echo $tweets;
echo json_encode($tweets);
?>
```

I am using Wamp server (PHP V5.5.12) and my code is working fine on it. But when I host my application on some free hosting sites (I have tried hostinger.in and 000webhost.com), this script fails and just prints 'null'.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just reduce the count to 10 or 20 & try it. Might be because of the connection speed. It happened to me when i tried this is on hosting sites.

Comment: It is still not working. I guess it is because hosting sites block some php functions and this api is using one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried in both, hostinger and 000webhost and several others. The reason they dont work is the library to connect to twitter uses php curl, and many free hosting have disabled curl, or outgoing connections or twitter refuses the curl connection when it comes from the ips from free hosting servers. For what I've read in internet it's probably because many hackers have been messing with twitter and hosting from free hosting accounts. So finding a free hosting with cpanel that works with Twitter API it's a challenge, i've tried over 20 and they dont work, some of them automatically deleted the account or the file or block the ftp access if you try to curl to twitter

Answer (score 2):

Likely to be related to the libraries available to you.

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of the script.

Check that cURL is installed on the cheap hosting as I believe that's the only php library that twitteroauth requires.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `TwitterOAuth` version? Your code seems to be so legacy and not compatible with latest version.

- https://twitteroauth.com/

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$lat = 26.511740;
$long = 80.234973;
$notweets = 100;

$ck = "XXXX";
$cs = "XXXX";
$ot = "XXXX-XXXX";
$os = "XXXX"; 

$to = new TwitterOAuth($ck, $cs, $ot, $os);

$tweets = $to->get('search/tweets', [
    'geocode' => "$lat,$long",
    'result_type' => 'recent',
    'count' => $notweets,
]);

if (isset($tweets->errors[0]->message)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $tweets->errors[0]->message;
} elseif (!is_array($tweets)) {
    echo 'Unknown Error';
} else {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($tweets);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `TwistOAuth` instead of `TwitterOAuth`. I'm the **author** of this library. This library is almost compabible with `TwitterOAuth`, but support strict exception handling. **Error reasons are always to be clear.**

- https://github.com/mpyw/TwistOAuth

```
<?php

require 'TwistOAuth.phar'; // Or 'vendor/autoload.php' for composer

$lat = 26.511740;
$long = 80.234973;
$notweets = 100;

$ck = "XXXX";
$cs = "XXXX";
$ot = "XXXX-XXXX";
$os = "XXXX"; 

try {

    $to = new TwistOAuth($ck, $cs, $ot, $os);
    $tweets = $to->get('search/tweets', [
        'geocode' => "$lat,$long",
        'result_type' => 'recent',
        'count' => $notweets,
    ]);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($tweets);
    echo '</pre>';

} catch (TwistException $e) {

    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

Which code do you like?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not see `[Works fine on localhost]` label. However, `TwistOAuth` will be always sure to provide you error reason, while `TwitterOAuth` just returns null. Try it.